# Хранить разные логи в БД

Tags: архитектура, база-данных, логирование, mysql

Здравствуйте, такой теоретически вопрос
Есть огромное количество логов разных типов, количество параметров у разных типов разное, сами параметры тоже отличаются
Подскажите, как правильно поступить? Создавать отдельную таблицу для каждого типа и использовать объединение при получении логов? Или хранить в одной таблице, оставляя пустыми некоторые параметры, в зависимости от типа? Или же сделать таблицу вроде
    logs
    time  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Типов много и предполагается их добавлять, основные
Пользователь вошел
time  name
Пользователь вышел
time  name
Пользователь ввел команду
time  name  command
Событие с номером
time  event  number
И еще довольно много...
Т.е. есть много общего, но в одной таблице без пустых строк никак(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему не сделать такую структуру

1) Таблица Logs

- Id
- Time
- EventId

2) Таблица EventTypes

- Id
- EventName (Название ивента)

3) Таблица LogEvents

- Id
- LogId (idшник лога)
- EventParamId (id параметра)
- Value (значение)

4) Таблица Parameters

- Id
- ParameterName
- ParameterType

При такой структуре безразлично сколько параметров у события, сколько типов событий. Если что-то непонятно могу уточнить.

Comment: Хорошая идея! Но отпугивает сложность запросов, например мне нужно получить логи с типом Join, где значение параметра Name уникально...! С такой структурой там будет что-то запредельное для меня =(

Comment: Без такой структуры всё будет гораздо хуже. В Join-ах нет ничего запредельного на самом деле.

Answer (score 1):

Пустных строк в базе необходимо избегать.
Я бы сделал разные таблицы под разные логи, с разным набором полей и не стал бы слеплять параметры в одно поле. По эти полям можно назначить индексы и делать выборку, формировать любым образом вывод данных.

Тут нужно видеть пример данных для разных типов логов, чтобы ответить точнее и с примером.

З.Ы. Таблицы и столбцы лучше называть понятными именами, а не p1, p2  и т.д.